# Curl error when trying to submit a form using rvest

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use the rvest package to automate computation of Blood Pressure SD scores across a cohort of patients. A tool that is online works well but when I try to scrape it I am running into difficulties. My main issue is that when I run the following code:

```
website<-read_html(URLencode("https://www.bcm.edu/bodycomplab/BPappZjs/BPvAgeAPPz.html",reserved = FALSE))
search<-html_form(website)[[1]]

search <- search %>% html_form_set(DOB = "01/01/2000",
                         MDate = "01/01/2005",
                         gender = 1,
                         units = 0,
                         height = 154,
                         systolic = 60,
                         diastolic = 120)

resp <- html_form_submit(search, submit = NULL)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

As far as I can tell the URL is correct? Is this the case that the website is blocking me from scraping the site or is there something else at play here.

Comment: That form uses javascript to send data to the server (see `search$action`). `rvest` cannot run javascript. You'd need to use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) that will allow you to interact with webpages that require javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!